# SpringBoot can't parse the yml format

Tags: java, spring, yaml

```
map:
  data:
    - id: 0
      points:
        - x: 0
          y: 0
          place:
            place_type: table
            place_id: 0
            place:
              place_type: prop
              place_id: 1
```

**Above is my yml configuration**
**The following is the corresponding configuration class**

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:floor_plan.yml"}, factory = YamlSourceFactory.class)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "map")
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class FloorPlan implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7889511292813486341L;
    private List<Graph> data;

    @Setter
    @Getter
    public static final class Graph implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8165584398823841393L;
        private int id;
        private List<Point> points;
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    public static final class Point implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3447034248118033017L;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private PlaceItem place;
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    public static final class PlaceItem implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8200048504444500019L;
        private String placeType;
        private int placeId;
        private PlaceItem place;
    }
}
```

PlaceItem is a recursive reference class
Automatic configuration cannot be injected into the place attribute in the PlaceItem
Is there a problem with my configuration? Or can't it be done?
Is there any way to do this configuration?

Comment: I tested your code without using `@PropertySource` because I don't know what `YamlSourceFactory` is, it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in the issue. Sorry, I didn't explain the role of YamlSourceFactory, which is used to load the yml source.    I have feedback to the SpringBoot team on this issue.   They really don't support such data injection, If you are interested, you can look at [16444](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16444),    Finally, I solved my problem in an imperfect way.